# Showing console output of a third party JNI library in an eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, java-native-interface, jpl

I am using JPL, a JNI library for interacting with Prolog from Java. In my application it is important to see the output that the Prolog engine generates (for example: when loading Prolog files, executing unit tests, etc). This is happening when I use the library in a standalone Java application.

However, when I pack my application as an Eclipse plug-in, I cannot see the JPL generated output anymore (such output is coming from the Prolog engine).

Does someone know if there is a way to see this output in the Eclipse console?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008675/how-can-i-redirect-jni-console-output-to-eclipse-console-view-when-eclipse-plug

Comment: Thanks for the link @vanaprogeja, unfortunately I do not have control over the JNI library I am using, conversely to the scenery of the question in the link. So I do not think I could use freopen as someone suggested.

Answer (score 0):

May be you could try to make a plugin out of your library ([hwoto](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseJarToPlugin/article.html)) and then hook a LogListener for this plugin [(like that](http://coopology.com/2011/04/using-log4j-in-eclipse-rcp-and-forcing-all-other-plugins-to-use-it-too/))?

Comment: thanks for your answer @Alexander. If I understood correctly the link proposes a mechanism for capturing log events and processing them afterwards (?) .Unfortunately, in my case I do not have proper log events, just output generated to the stdio from my JNI library.

Comment: But can you still try to create a plugin out of a library, may be in this case you will see the output?

Comment: mmm, not sure if I get your point. My application is already an eclipse plug-in, and I do not see the output when deployed as a jar file dropped in the plugins folder (I can see the output if I choose "Run as/Eclipse Application" from the development environment). I do not think it will make a difference if I have two plugins instead (one with the library and one with the rest of the application) as I understand you suggest (?)

Comment: Are you running it with -consoleLog/-debug argument?